# Prove $\Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right) =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)}}{2\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

With $\text{Re}(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}})$, I expanded it with polar form and found the real component to be

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos(n\theta)-\cos((n+1)\theta)}{2{\sin}^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$

where the numerator was derived from.
$(1-\text{cis}(n+1)x) \cdot (1-\cos x+i\sin x)$

I graphed it and it seems different to what is asked.

Have I made a mistake? if not, how do I proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct, now by [sum to product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) we obtain

$$\cos(n\theta)-\cos((n+1)\theta) = -2\sin\left(\frac{(2n+1)\theta}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{-\theta}2\right)$$

which leads to the desired expression.